Unity shader graph converting issue
Does anyone know how to convert this float(actually vector2?) on the image into kinda list or smth like that with just float (not vector2).
I want to use this gaussian noise to randomize my amplitude.
I'm a bit new to the graph system, so sorry if it's not a big deal to solve

Use the node Split.
It works for this kinda types that has multiple values internally and can take each value.

i have tried to use it before, but it didnt work. If i connect this to my logic, it throws an exception kinda: "You cant values like this to vertices".
